# Read string C - Linux

Tags: c, string

I'm trying to read a string and print it in `Linux` using:

```
cc child.c -o child
```

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {  

    char st[100];

    scanf("%s", &st);
    printf("%s", st);

    return 0;
}
```

However I encounter this warning that will not allow me to compile.

> child.c: In function ‘main’: 
>   child.c:8:2: warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘char (*)[100]’ [-Wformat=]
>         scanf("%s", &st);

How can I solve it? Thanks!

Comment: Works fine for me! (Only think to change: `scanf("%s", &st);` to `scanf("%s", st);`)

Comment: Good that you had your compiler warnings enabled.

Answer (score 4):

In C, when passed to a function, array names converted to pointer to the first element of array. No need to place `&` before `st`.  Change

```
scanf("%s", &st);
```

to

```
scanf("%s", st);
```

Answer (score 2):

In C array types degenerate to pointers. So when you take the address of an array, you actually get a pointer to a pointer. Just pass the array itself to scanf.